# Facebook Graph API - all account pages + posts data

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having an issue trying to write the correct GET request using the Facebook API explorer tool.

I'd like to access all my Facebook pages and the below data from their respective posts. I can achieve this by adding the page name manually, but I'd like it to be more dynamic if I was to add more pages in the future.

```
posts?ids=Pagename,Pagename,Pagename,Pagename&fields=message,created_time,full_picture,shares,likes.summary(true).limit(0),comments.summary(true).limit(0),from,permalink_url
```

I know you can use `me/accounts` but I've had no luck when trying the append the above posts GET request.

Furthermore, I'd like to get the page profile picture from the posts. Just adding `picture` to the above request doesn't work. Since the profile picture is displayed in each post I'd imagine there is a key to access it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#fieldexpansion

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer after I reread the documentation

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/me/accounts?fields=picture,posts{message,created_time,full_picture,shares,likes.summary(true).limit(0),comments.summary(true).limit(0),from,permalink_url}
```

All attached accounts profile picture + above data.